# For each and every element want to add unique content:url();

Tags: css, css-selectors

When I hover over word it should shows an appropriate pict as background

Considering to make it with js dataset but it still won't work

```html
       <ul>
         <li><a  href="#">word</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#">word2</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#">word3</a></li>
         <li><a  href="#">word4</a></li>
       </ul>
```

```css
 li a {
      display: block;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 3.3rem;
      color: $dark-clr;
      padding: 10px;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
      font-weight: bold;
      letter-spacing: 1.2px;
      text-transform: capitalize;

      &:hover {
        color: $icons-clr;
      }
    }
    li a::before {
      content: url(/pict/1.jpg);
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      opacity: 0;
      z-index: -1;
      transition: all 0.4s ease;
    }

    li a:hover::before {
      opacity: 0.5;
    }
```

Can't use attr src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply the image as a `background-image` on the pseudo element (:before). You will also need to apply `position: relative` to the anchors so the background element is positioned accordingly. Then you can apply unique background by giving each item in the list a unique class or id.

```css
li a {
  position: relative; /* so the absolutely positioned pseudo element works */
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 3.3rem;
  color: $dark-clr;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
  font-weight: bold;
  letter-spacing: 1.2px;
  text-transform: capitalize;
  &:hover {
    color: $icons-clr;
  }
}

li a::before {
  content: ''; /* empty content */
  background-size: cover; /* make sure the backgrounds cover the element */
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%; /* cover the full width of the anchor */
  height: 100%; /* cover the full height of the anchor */
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: all 0.4s ease;
}

li a:hover::before {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

/* unique backgrounds for each list item anchor */
li a#item1::before {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/250/50');
}
li a#item2::before {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/200/50');
}
li a#item3::before {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/220/50');
}
li a#item4::before {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/240/50');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#" id="item1">word</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="item2">word2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="item3">word3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="item4">word4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: that definetily works,thanks